# Android webview dark theme not showing correct color

Tags: css, webview, colors, themes

I'm using dark theme in android webview,

```
WebSettingsCompat.setAlgorithmicDarkeningAllowed(settings, true);
```

but some of the colors not showing correctly on real devices, but emulator shows correct.
Why and what should I do?

correct color:
[image]

not correct
[image]